# yii CGridView: concatenate string with variable in link

Tags: php, yii

Cant concatenate string with variable.

Waiting your advices, guys.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'columns'=>array(
        array (
            //'value'=>'CHtml::link("Some text", Yii::app()->createUrl("/example/registration&exampleID=".$data->exampleID))',  // DONT work
            'value'=>'CHtml::link("Some text", Yii::app()->createUrl("/example/registration&exampleID=112"))',
            //'value'=>'CHtml::link("Some text", "/index.php?r=/example/registration&exampleID=".$data->exampleID)',            // DONT work
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: what about ``'value' => '$data->exampleID'`` ?

Comment: may be I have empty variable? Vlad, this show me anything? i see nothong now..

Comment: Yep. It can be a ``null``, or ``false``...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `function` for `value`:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
'columns'=>array(
    array (
     'value' => function ($data, $row) {
         echo CHtml::link("Some text", Yii::app()->createUrl("/example/registration&exampleID=".$data->exampleID));
       },
      )  
   ),
));
```

This can be helpful.

Comment: Same thing. I think here is empty variable...  But why? What to do with tihs?

Comment: @hamed He can use string too: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CComponent#evaluateExpression-detail

Comment: Right, But I think function is more readable. I always use function inside cgridview columns.

Comment: @VitalikZenin Maybe the `$data->exampleID` is empty.

Comment: Yeah. Something wrong with $data i think. But dont know why. I will use another way to get this data... Thanks guys.